# Changing the form dictionary is displayed

Tags: python

I have a text file as follows:

```
Monstera Deliciosa
2018-11-03 18:21:26
Tropical/sub-Tropical plant
Leathery leaves, mid to dark green
Moist and well-draining soil
Semi-shade/full shade light requirements
Water only when top 2 inches of soil is dry
Intolerant to root rot
Propagate by cuttings in water

Strelitzia Nicolai (White Birds of Paradise)
2018-11-05 10:12:15
Semi-shade, full sun
Dark green leathery leaves
Like lots of water,but soil cannot be water-logged
Like to be root bound in pot
```

I have managed to get all these data to be displayed as a form of dictionary with the key as the plant name (e.g. {key = Monstera Deliciosa and value = rest of info below it made into a list}

Below is my code attached.

```
import itertools as it

plants = {}
with open('myplants.txt') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            p = next(f).rstrip()
            plants[p] = list(l.rstrip() for l in it.takewhile(lambda line: line != '\n', f))
        except StopIteration:
            break

for plantname, details in list(plants.items()):
    print(f"{plantname}'s info is: {details}")
```

And the output is:

```
Monstera Deliciosa's info is: ['2018-11-03 18:21:26', 'Tropical/sub-Tropical plant', 'Leathery leaves, mid to dark green', 'Moist and well-draining soil', 'Semi-shade/full shade light requirements', 'Water only when top 2 inches of soil is dry', 'Intolerant to root rot', 'Propagate by cuttings in water']
Strelitzia Nicolai (White Birds of Paradise)'s info is: ['2018-11-05 10:12:15', 'Semi-shade, full sun', 'Dark green leathery leaves', 'Like lots of water,but soil cannot be water-logged', 'Like to be root bound in pot']
```

Is there any way to display it in the below format with the For Loop mentioned above?

```
Monstera Deliciosa's info is:
['2018-11-03 18:21:26', 
 'Tropical/sub-Tropical plant', 
 'Leathery leaves, mid to dark green', 
 'Moist and well-draining soil', 
 'Semi-shade/full shade light requirements', 
 'Water only when top 2 inches of soil is dry', 
 'Intolerant to root rot', 
 'Propagate by cuttings in water']

Strelitzia Nicolai (White Birds of Paradise)'s info is:
['2018-11-05 10:12:15', 
 'Semi-shade, full sun', 
 'Dark green leathery leaves', 
 'Like lots of water,
  but soil cannot be water-logged', 
 'Like to be root bound in pot']
```

Meaning I would like to make the text readable in the IDE like it is in the text file.
Thank you in advance for your generous help. :)

Comment: `"\n".join(details)` would be a starting point.

Comment: move the prints onto separate lines and use @jassonharper suggustion. `print(plantname)` and `print("\n".join(details))`

Comment: Look into the pprint module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jasonharper and @joshmeranda already pretty much answered this. Essentially, this code will format your text like you wanted:

```
for plantname, details in list(plants.items()):
    print(f"{plantname}'s info is:\n" + '\n'.join(details), "\n")
```